# Significato di "dànno a dividere la calce secondaria" in questo contesto

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Ivi la Natura vivente dispiega rigogliosa la sua potenza; ivi l'eccelse Querce, i Sugheri, i Lecci, i Frassini, gli Olmi rivestono l'erte, e le vallate delle falde, mentre gli Acrifogli, i Pini, gli Aceri si estendono fin presso le sommità ghiacciate, le quali o sono adorne di Faggi, o calve affatto **dànno a dividere la calce secondaria**; ivi prosperano ogni maniera di arbori e di erbe, che olezzano d'ogni intorno grata fragranza, ed offrono al botanico moltissimo materiale per le dotte sue lucubrazioni.

Conosco il significato delle singole parole in questo passaggio, tuttavia non riesco a capire il senso della frase "dànno a dividere la calce secondaria". Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La calce secondaria è il [marmo](https://books.google.it/books?id=shv7Fhkmxn8C&pg=PA549&lpg=PA549&dq=calce%20secondaria&source=bl&ots=fmbplBCjRY&sig=c9kq8DnxwNzG2zYV5Eg-sS8gUpo&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiv3uL5jcbbAhXrLMAKHSJGBXEQ6AEILTAC#v=onepage&q=calce%20secondaria&f=false).

Qui viene descritta la varietà di un paesaggio montuoso in cui varie specie di piante a volte "dividono" i tratti in cui affiora la pietra marmorea, che immagino siano punti spogli e privi di vegetazione.